# Formula to calculate the nearest distance from a point to a volume in 3D space?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am looking for a method to calculate the **nearest** distance from a point (x-y-z) to a volume in 3-dimensional space. 
Assumption: The point is not inside the volume.
Assumption: The volume is a closed coherent shape.

Is there a conventional name for this problem?

Bonus points if you can link to or include a function in a common programming language for doing this.

Comment: Well, since you are looking for a programming solution, why not sample the space with a Monte Carlo method (or rejection method) and take the minimum distance to $(x,y,z)$ of each found point?

Comment: The nearest distance would be a point lying in the surface, which would then give a distance of $0$. Are there any other constraints on the point?

Comment: @Denis28, the point $(x,y,z)$ is fixed, and assumed outside the volume.

Answer (score 2):

If I interpreted the problem correctly, let your surface be $z=f(x,y)$ and your point $P(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, which is fixed, using the distance formula
$$D(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(f(x,y)-z_0)^2}$$
you want to solve the system
$$\begin{cases}\partial_xD(x,y)=0\\
\partial_yD(x,y)=0
\end{cases}$$
and check using the $Hessian
$ that the points found provide a minimum. Add the additional constraint that $f(x^*,y^*)>0$, where $x^*$ and $y^*$ are the possible mins.

You can also use Lagrange Multipliers, which exploits the fact that the shortest distance from a point to a surface is perpendicular to the surface.